# WebApi Map Router

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes

I am using WebApi in our project. We have same controller name defined under different sub-folder. Like:

```
Controllers
    |----Admin
    |      |----MyProjectsController.cs
    |
    |----User
          |----MyProjectsController.cs
```

How can we define a route config for such scenario.

```
/api/admin/MyProjects
/api/user/MyProjects
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly supported by route templates because the namespace is not considered when using Web API controllers. You need to use Web API routing attributes. And you have to manually specify them (they now nothing about the folder or namespace in which the Controller is included).

Particularly you should have a look at [Route prefixes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes). For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("Admin")]
public class MyProjectController: ApiController
```